# ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. Gaslimit already set

Tags: solidity, erc-721, gas-limit, brownie

I'm getting this error when I try to run my Brownie Python script:

```
myAwesomeGasLimit = 200000
def enter_for_free():
    account = get_account()
    lottery = Lottery[-1]
    tx = lottery.claimFreeEntry(
        '0xD3311541C02595112db0e43F241e198E86079349',
        {"from" : account, "gasLimit" : myAwesomeGasLimit}
        )
    tx.wait(1)
    print("You successfully entered for free")
```

And here is the function from the solidity smart contract:

```
function claimFreeEntry(address _erc721_contract) public {
        require(IERC721(msg.sender).balanceOf(_erc721_contract) > 0, "You are not eligible to play for free");
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }
```

As you can see there is not much going on, nevertheless I haven't been able to solve it for one hour now. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Exact Error: `ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'execution reverted'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually.`

Comment: There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71194882/execution-reverted-during-call-this-transaction-will-likely-revert-if-you-wish

Comment: You have inverted contract and sender. Correct to this: `IERC721(_erc721_contract).balanceOf(msg.sender)`

Comment: @0xSanson Thank you!!